# SQL Server subquery help please? (looking to use an existing select query as a subquery)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, select

I have a stored procedure that is working well, it's a select query. I want to change what is returned though with some aggregations, using the current query as a subquery. The current query returns data as such:

```
A  1/1/12
A  1/2/12
A  1/3/12
B  2/1/12
B  5/3/12
B  5/5/12
```

I'd like to see this as:

```
A  1/1/12  1/3/12
B  2/1/12  5/5/12
```

So I want the min of the date value, then the max of the date value, per stock symbol. Here is the current sproc that I'd like to stick with:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sprocSymbsDatesForHistoricalPricingVol

AS

DECLARE @NxtAvailableDataDownloadDate date

SET @NxtAvailableDataDownloadDate = dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDate()

SELECT Symbol, TradingDate
FROM (SELECT tblSymbolsMain.Symbol, tblTradingDays.TradingDate
      FROM tblSymbolsMain CROSS JOIN
      tblTradingDays
      WHERE (tblTradingDays.TradingDate <= @NxtAvailableDataDownloadDate)) AS T1
      WHERE (NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT TradeDate, Symbol
              FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol
              WHERE (TradeDate = T1.TradingDate) AND (Symbol = T1.Symbol)))
ORDER BY Symbol, TradingDate
```

My attempts to wrap that select query as a subquery aren't working... any takers? I'm sure it's quite simple. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Symbol, MIN(TradingDate), Max(TradingDate)
FROM (
SELECT Symbol, TradingDate
FROM (SELECT tblSymbolsMain.Symbol, tblTradingDays.TradingDate
      FROM tblSymbolsMain CROSS JOIN
      tblTradingDays
      WHERE (tblTradingDays.TradingDate <= @NxtAvailableDataDownloadDate)) AS T1
      WHERE (NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT TradeDate, Symbol
              FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol
              WHERE (TradeDate = T1.TradingDate) AND (Symbol = T1.Symbol)))) t
GROUP BY Symbol
```

Comment: Won't that just give me min/ max dates of the entire data set, the same for each record, instead of the min/ max for the actual symbols? (correlated)

Comment: +1. Beat me to it by about three characters and a mouse click. :)

Comment: No, because of the group by. Of course, you could just try it and find out. :)

Comment: @StatsViaCsh the group by should give you the min and max per symbol

Comment: @KenWhite this happens to me at least once a day :D thanks for upvote

Comment: @Ken Or, I could ask, and maybe here some additional insight on syntax and as to why (which I did get... the group by... thanks :)

Comment: @StatsViaCsh: Bassam gave you the syntax, and a quick test would have told you whether it worked or not.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh, no. That's not what I'm saying. :) I'm saying that, given the answer, it sometimes is a good learning technique to try it to see if it works, and then see if you can figure out why it works (or why not). I find I learn more that way, because it gets me to think about the solution more. That could just be me, though. :)

Comment: @Ken Thanks... I was joking, I hope it came across... I agree. The immediate full answer isn't always the best for a newb.

Answer (score -2):

```
create table TestTab(symbol char(1), date datetime)


insert into TestTab values ('A','1/1/12')
insert into TestTab values('A','1/2/12')
insert into TestTab values('A','1/3/12')
insert into TestTab values('B','2/1/12')
insert into TestTab values('B','5/3/12')
insert into TestTab values('B','5/5/12')


select mi.symbol, mi.min_dt, ma.max_dt
from
(
    select symbol, min(date) min_dt
    from TestTab
    group by symbol
) mi full outer join
(

    select symbol, max(date) max_dt
    from TestTab
    group by symbol
) ma on (mi.symbol = ma.symbol)
```